# Exchange a large JSON object using TCP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, tcp

I want to send a large object encoded in JSON across a TCP connection, both ends implemented in Ruby. The problem is that the object may be received in chunks (there is no guarantee that one send corresponds to one receive in TCP).

I hate reinventing the wheel, so I ask to those that are more proficient than me in Ruby if there is good and simple practice to deal with the problem (well, if the problem exists).

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you wanting a streaming JSON encoder/decoder? The entire purpose of TCP is to guarantee 1:1 send:receive of bytes in-order. You don't have to worry about reimplementing it.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing TCP with UDP? With UDP you would have to worry about incomplete chunks and receive order. But Ruby's standard [TCP Socket](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) class can be treated just like a file.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. How big is your JSON blob? Why can't you send it as one chunk and let TCP deal with it? Most servers are capable of handling huge MB files easily. A HTTP/JSON (AKA REST) server written in Sinatra with a simple OpenURI client should be easy to write and handle most tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about knowing when the entire JSON document is received, then you need to deal with framing. A TCP connection provides only one guarantee: That the byte stream will be received in-order. It doesn't help distinguish one chunk of data from the next.

For that you need a framing system. For example, Websocket is a common standard for sending framed data over a TCP connection and receiving it as distinct messages. If you need to send multiple JSON objects over the same connection it'd be worth studying how that works if not simply using that protocol.

Maybe you're mistaking the "chunk" nature of TCP as in writing a single JSON object to one end of the stream may result in multiple reads on the receiver's side. This is true, you may receive the data byte by byte, but this is to be expected, and you keep reading until you're satisfied you've received enough data to continue.

The naive approach here is to keep appending the data you receive to a buffer and process it when the connection is properly closed.

A good Websocket driver will take care of this for you and will deliver only completed messages to your code.

Comment: Yes, Tadman, this was the problem. And you guessed right that I want to send several objects on the same connection. I will evaluate the websocket solution even if, at first sight, it has a heavy footprint. But probably the solution is to write myself a bufferedReader, or open/close the socket for every object sent (which sounds impractical). Thank you.

Comment: Websocket is pretty light-weight compared to other solutions and has the advantage of already having been written so you can integrate with other systems without having to do a lot of work. Writing a good framing protocol yourself is tricky and easy to get horribly wrong. For example, the first prototype version of Websocket used `0x00` and `0xFF` to delineate beginning and end of message, a naive approach that quickly proved to be nothing but trouble because of conflict with binary data. The current protocol is a significant improvement and handles binary data without issue.

Comment: Totally agree. Framing is a headache: I was considering a length|value protocol, but it is limited and fragile, and my feeling was exactly like reinventing a (wood) wheel. Instead I've given a look at websockets (https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-server and -client) and this looks to be the right solution.